# putting a visualized binary tree into a tuple

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples, binary-search-tree

i got this binary tree

[image]

i want to put this in a tuple with the structure (left_subtree, key, right_subtree) (where left_subtree and right_subtree are themselves tuples.
how can i do this in a right way?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


tree_tuple = (((None, 6, None), 4,2,(9, 7, 10)), 1,
              ((13, 11, 14),8, (15, 12, 16), 5, 3))


print(len(tree_tuple))


def parse_tuple(data):
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
    elif data is None:
        node = None
    else:
        node = TreeNode(data)
    return node


tree = parse_tuple(tree_tuple)

print(tree.right.right.left.right.key)
```

i tried this but obviously there is something wrong with my tuple structure or even my tree itself

Comment: *"I want to put this in a tuple with the structure"*: it seems your code does the opposite, and takes a tuple as *input* and builds a tree of `TreeNode` instances? Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you are trying to do.

You parse_tuple does indeed also give 12 as the answer, the issue was in your formatting of tree_tuple.

I just modified it as to how I would approach it.

The next step is to account for None :)

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def parse_tuple(data):
    if isinstance(data, tuple) and len(data) == 3:
        node = TreeNode(data[1])
        node.left = parse_tuple(data[0])
        node.right = parse_tuple(data[2])
        return node
    elif data is None:
        return None
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid Tuple Format")


tree_tuple = (
    (((None, 6, None), 4, ((None, 9, None), 7, (None, 10, None))), 2, None),
    1,
    (
        None,
        3,
        (
            (
                ((None, 13, None), 11, (None, 14, None)),
                8,
                ((None, 15, None), 12, (None, 16, None)),
            ),
            5,
            None,
        ),
    ),
)

tree = parse_tuple(tree_tuple)


print("LEFT")
print(tree.left.key)
print(tree.left.left.key)
print(tree.left.left.left.key)
print(tree.left.left.right.key)
print(tree.left.left.right.left.key)
print(tree.left.left.right.right.key)

print("\nRIGHT")
print(tree.right.key)
print(tree.right.right.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.left.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.left.left.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.left.right.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.right.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.right.left.key)
print(tree.right.right.left.right.right.key)
```

Comment: the left side of tree is correct but the right side is not.
i used this function to display the keys.
`def display_keys(node, space='\t', level=0):
    # print(node.key if node else None, level)

    # If the node is empty
    if node is None:
        print(space*level + '∅')
        return

    # If the node is a leaf
    if node.left is None and node.right is None:
        print(space*level + str(node.key))
        return`